# MOVE named cursor in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I use named cursor in psycopg2. How to reset cursor start from 0? I used the following code, but no effect and has an error.

```
with conn.cursor(name="curname") as cursor:
    cursor.itersize = 100
    cursor.execute("MOVE ABSOLUTE 0 IN curname",)
```

error:

```
LINE 1: DECLARE "curname" CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR MOVE ABSOLUTE 0 IN.
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to initialize the cursor with a query using `cursor.execute()`. Then you can use the same functions (`fetchone()`, `fetchall()` etc) as with the client-side cursors.

The SQL `MOVE` command is implemented by [scroll(value[, mode='relative'])](http://psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.scroll) in psycopg2.

Simple example (the query generates 10 rows with integers from 1 to 10):

```python
with conn.cursor(name="curname") as cursor:
    cursor.itersize = 100
    cursor.execute("select generate_series(1, 10)")
    
    print('first:', cursor.fetchone())
    cursor.scroll(9, mode='absolute')
    print('tenth:', cursor.fetchone())
    cursor.scroll(0, mode='absolute')
    print('first again:', cursor.fetchone())
```

Output:

```
first: (1,)
tenth: (10,)
first again: (1,)
```

Read more about [Server side cursors.](http://psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors)